# how to use bootstrap popup in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Morning all, i'm still learning how to use bootstrap popup in CI, here the code i'm already tried

```
<?php foreach ($tbl_bet_spot as $data) {?>  
    <tr>
        <td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some content inside the popover" ><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>
        <td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" rel="<?php echo site_url('account/detail_player_id/'.$data->id);?>"><?php echo $data->id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->bet;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->total_bet;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->win;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->lose;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

about script is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.loveit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('rel');
 $.ajax({
        url: targetUrl,
        type: "GET",
        success:function(html){
            $(document).ready(function(){
            //alert("done");
            $('#view-list-round-history').html(html);
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
            });
        },
        error:function (){
            alert("testing error");
        }
    });
});
```

before this, i'm already create like this `<td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" rel="<?php echo site_url('account/detail_player_id/'.$data->id);?>"><?php echo $data->id;?></td>` result is, it show in html `$('#view-list-round-history').html(html);`

problem is, i still try create bootstrap popup, when i click this `<td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some content inside the popover" ><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>` i want showing result query from controller in popup, but this code not work. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($tbl_bet_spot as $data) {?>  
    <tr>
        <td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some content inside the popover" ><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a></td>
        <td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" rel="<?php echo site_url('account/detail_player_id/'.$data->id);?>"><?php echo $data->id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->bet;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->total_bet;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->win;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->lose;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

missed a closing td in the following statement,

```
<td><a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some content inside the popover" ><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>
```

Comment: there are two anchor tags with class loveit, you gave rel attribute to the second one and not the first one, can I ask why?

Comment: ah sry if you confuse about it, the second one is code i use now, and showed in ajax. the first one is what i want it now, showed like second ones, but in pop up, can it be done?

Comment: Yes it can be done, where is your modal?  and where is data-target="" attribute in, <a class="loveit" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Some content inside the popover" ><?php echo $data->round_id;?></a>, you need to add data-target="" and modal's html.